# Populate fields with measure values

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, linear-referencing

I have a feature class containing linear features with from/to measure values applied. Is there a way I can map those measures into the attribute table in "Beginning" and "End" fields? Using arcmap 10.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

figured it out using python:

use field calculator to return the MAX M measures:

```
!Shape.extent.MMax!
```

use field calculator to return the MIN M measures:

```
!Shape.extent.MMin!
```